How to only show final summary table in Cypress test result, run mode
I am trying to show only summary table in output,
and remove all success log, failure log, and all other information etc

Things i tried

i tried cypress run --quiet mode, but it's not that quiet, it still prints output
there is also mochawesome reporter support , but it does not prints summary table that i need

Any help is appreciated

I use simple shell commands to filter the output so I can access only the summary of test results:
> cypress run > result.txt
> cat result.txt | sed -n -e '/Run Finished/,$p'

This saves output to a file result.txt and outputs everything starting from the line containing "Run Finished" to the end of the file.
